# How to deal with booleans in NSMutableArrays?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, boolean

Can someone tell me why my application crashes here ?

and why it does not crash when i replace the YES objects with NSString values ?

all i want to do is to store boolean data into array and to modify these data later,
can someone please tell me how to do this ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:YES, YES, YES, YES, nil];
    NSLog([arr objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

YES and NO are BOOLs, which is *not* an Objective-C class. Foundation containers can only store Objective-C objects.

You need to wrap them in an NSNumber, like:

```
NSNumber* yesObj = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                               yesObj, yesObj, yesObj, yesObj, nil];
NSLog(@"%d", [[arr objectAtIndex:1] boolValue]);
```

The reason why it accepts NSString is because an NSString *is* a kind of Objective-C class.

Comment: To get the original `BOOL` value, you can use `BOOL b = [[array objectAtIndex:i] boolValue]`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, i wish objective-c had the feature of auto boxing / unboxing as it is in Java, anyway objective-c is really a painfull language :S

Comment: @anasnakawa: Objective-C is quite a thin layer over plain C, which is where most of the pain will come from.

Comment: @anasnakawa: that's what I thought at first, but in many ways Objective-C is closer to the spirit of real object oriented programming than Java is.  Once you get used to the quirks, you may find it to be better.